# Google Maps v3,  error message "Google is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am getting errors on my site just trying to implement the basic "Hello world" application:

```
<div id="map"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
});
```

The error I get is:

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined'

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify the version, but you should probably use the googleapis.com domain instead of google.com; both should work, but the former is preferred over the latter. Can you show us the full code, i.e. what's in myOptions for instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your source is wrong, I also suggest specifing the exact version you want to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>
```

That should help.

Comment: Thanks! this solved it, the annoying thing was that it was working fine on both my local server and my linux/apache hosting, when I went to move it across to my production  box it died, thanks again!

Comment: Also make sure you're using http for IE8 instead of https ... not sure why

Answer (score 2):

Lots of things from your code:

1. You have given `document.ready` but there is no `jQuery` link
2. Your  `document.ready` has to be inside `<script>` tags `</script>`
3. You should also have given the `height` and `width` to the `div` in which you are holding the map, as such it is just an empty tag.
4. You have defined myOptions for Map, and there is nothing to interpret for map as what are the options to be taken into consideration while loading the map**

Here is a Complete example:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Please put your jquery here"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.65, -73.95);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
$("document").ready(function () {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI Sorry that was a complete faux pas on my copy pastery -
I was indeed using a jquery lib and had enclosed the script  tags around the jcall to the doc ready function and I managed to miss off the my options section of the code from the example - sorry hard to debug with out the correct info I know, although none of those errors would have caused the error seeing in console.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens in the browser Google Chrome if your main site is in a https platform and the map is in a http. For showing the map you have a shield in URL box, just click the shield and it should show it.

Comment: you are right it was when i added https it stopped working

Comment: Use a relative protocol indication:  <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/path/to/js.js"> ...